# Can $F_n+n$ have arbitary many distinct prime factors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, prime-factorization

For a positive integer , define $$f(n):=\omega(F_n+n)$$ where $F_n$ denotes the $n$-th fibonacci-number and $\omega(n)$ denotes the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

Define $g(k)$ as the smallest positive integer $g$ with $f(g)=k$ , if such an integer exists and undefined otherwise.

> Is g a total function ? In other words , can $F_n+n$ have any given positive number of disctint prime factors ?

The values of $g$ upto $k=10$ :

```
gp > for(k=1,10,s=1;while(omega(fibonacci(s)+s)<>k,s=s+1);print(k,"  ",s))
1  1
2  5
3  12
4  19
5  36
6  47
7  89
8  203
9  190
10  144
gp >
```

Further , we have $g(11)=358$ and $g(k)>358$ for every $k>11$ since $n=358$ is the first case with at least $11$ prime factors. Similar , we have $g(12)=420$ and $g(k)>420$ for $k>12$

Comment: Maybe asking if $f$ is unbounded is more approachable?

Comment: [$g(14)\le 902$](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=I%28n%29%2Bn&use=n&n=902&VP=on&VC=on&EV=on&OD=on&PR=on&FF=on&PRP=on&CF=on&U=on&C=on&perpage=1&format=1&sent=Show)